# Android Handler: Send 8 different messages: handler finds 8 messages but only used the last message

Tags: android, view, handler, message

I am new to Android and found out that to keep updating the main view I had to create a thread to handle various process and then pass back updates to the main view. I decided to use the Handler class to do this.  The view in this example has a button to activate the code and a tablelayout to display the messages received - representing a stage of the process.

The problem is that I send 8 different messages and I can see 8 messages coming back in the handler, but all 8 have the same contents as message 8 only.

I was expecting the handler to pick the messages up in sequence.

Any suggestions on a better way of doing this always welcome to learn.

Here is the code:

`

```
public class messageHandlerTest extends Activity {

protected TextView textView;
protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String[] status = (String[]) msg.obj;
            createTableRow(status);
            Log.e("Got a new message",status[0]+":"+status[1]);
        }
    };

Button btnStartProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
    textView.setText("");
    //Getting response from server with Network SSID and Password

    Button connectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
    addListenerOnButton();
} // End of create

protected class connectWiFi extends Thread implements Runnable {
    //tokens1 = new String[0];
    public void run(){
    try {
        String[] messageString = new String[2];
        Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
        messageString[0]="OK";
        messageString[1]="Number 1";
        message.obj = messageString;
        handler.sendMessage(message);

        message = handler.obtainMessage();
        messageString[0]="OK";
        messageString[1]= "Number 2";
        message.obj = messageString;
        handler.sendMessage(message);
        message = handler.obtainMessage();
        messageString[0]="OK";
        messageString[1] = "Number 3";
        message.obj = messageString;
        handler.sendMessage(message);
        message = handler.obtainMessage();
        messageString[0]="OK";
        messageString[1] = "Number 4";
        message.obj = messageString;
        handler.sendMessage(message);

                    message = handler.obtainMessage();
                    messageString[0] = "OK";
                    messageString[1] = "Number 5";
                    message.obj = messageString;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);

                    message = handler.obtainMessage();
                    messageString[0] = "OK";
                    messageString[1] = "Number 6";
                    message.obj = messageString;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);

                    message = handler.obtainMessage();
                    messageString[0] = "OK";
                    messageString[1] = "Number 7";
                    message.obj = messageString;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);

                    message = handler.obtainMessage();
                    messageString[0] = "OK";
                    messageString[1] = "Number 8";
                    message.obj = messageString;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception found","bugger");
    }
    }// End or run
}// End of class

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
    btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                connectWiFi connectwifi = new connectWiFi();
                connectwifi.start();
                }

            });

}
private void createTableRow(String[] stage) {
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.statusTable);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tr.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tr.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    TextView tvStatus = new TextView(this);
    tvStatus.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tvStatus.setPadding(2,1,1,2);
    tvStatus.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    tvStatus.setText(stage[0]); // Status
    TextView tvStage = new TextView(this);
    tvStage.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tvStage.setPadding(2,1,1,2);
    tvStage.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    tvStage.setText(stage[1]); // Stage
    tr.addView(tvStatus);
    tr.addView(tvStage);
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

The result of this code looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does `Log.e("Got a new message",status[0]+":"+status[1]);` give correct values?

Comment: @vikram Log.e provides the same result as the view i.e. all show 8!

Comment: @JanBo - I got this code as an example from here: http://madskool.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/dr-android-answers-threads-and-the-ui/

Comment: The example I used was the 3rd one down... all help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect what may be happening is that you continually modify the same reference String[] named messageString while never creating a new one.  Passing that by reference and then continuing to change the values there are probably what's resulting in this outcome.

A few things,

1. When using handlers try to use the what field for return code.  For instnace, your OK string (if it is just for a status) you would be better off defining int constant return types.
2. As JanBo mentioned, you don't want to be extending Thread and implementing Runnable.
3. It really depends on what you're trying to do exactly but the Handler message queue callback pattern is one of many you can choose to accomplish what you want.  In the interest of learning another method, take a look at a blog post I wrote [here](http://blog.vaporstream.com/blog/2013/07/09/concurrency-patterns-intent-service/) which explains how you can delegate off-UI thread tasks to an IntentService and call back to your Activity when it finishes.

Comment: Thank you Andrew as below that was the problem and proved it to myself. I will have a look at the blog.

Comment: Any chance of explaining why extending Thread and implementing Runnable is such a bad thing. If I do not have Run in the class it does not work?  But once again I will look at your blog - so thank you for your help.

Comment: OK - not to worry removed the implement Runnable and works fine - so thanks again.

Comment: @ZipNFC What JanBo meant was: You should be doing either one of those. Either extend `Thread`, or implement `Runnable`. Doing both at the same time is not required.

Comment: Thanks @Vikram -  have a great weekend all - back to coding school for me.  Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

For sending data through handler you can use bundle as data of message object that you want to send to handler. Like this code :

```java
// receieve message in handleMessage method of handler of your controller (e.g. on UI thread)
handler = new Handler() { 
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle b = msg.getData();
        Integer value = b.getInt("KEY");
        ...
    }
};

// Sending message in a background thread
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Message msg = new Message();
        final Bundle b = new Bundle();
        Integer value = 1;
        b.putInt("KEY", value);
        msg.setData(b);
        handler.sendMessage(msg);    
    }
).start();
```

Comment: Great job :) You saved plenty of my time. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose what's happening is that: `messageString`, which you create only once, is being updated while `message` is waiting in the queue. Change your code like this:

```
String[] messageString1 = new String[2];
Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
messageString1[0]="OK";
messageString1[1]="Number 1";
message.obj = messageString1;
handler.sendMessage(message);

String[] messageString2 = new String[2];
message = handler.obtainMessage();
messageString2[0]="OK";
messageString2[1]= "Number 2";
message.obj = messageString2;
handler.sendMessage(message);

....
....
```

Comment: Very nice explanation of how to fix the current code and it worked - so thank you very much. What a silly mistake, but based on the feedback above I obviously can vastly improve my code and method used!

Comment: @ZipNFC You are welcome. Please make it a habit of accepting answers that you find suitable. Have a good weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am doing this in the right place, but I thought I would post back my refactored code based on the help I received here and it might help someone else.  This works well for me and the code looks quite neat, but any feedback on how this could be improved or made more efficient would always be appreciated. Also let me know if I am doing this in the wrong place!

```
public class messageHandlerTest2 extends Activity {

protected TextView textView;
protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        createTableRow((mymessageObject) msg.obj);
    }
};  //Set-up handler to be used later

Button btnStartProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
    addListenerOnButton();
} // End of create

protected class connectWiFi extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sendMessage(true,"Number 1"); // send if OK and a stage message
            sendMessage(true,"Number 2");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 3");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 4");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 5");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 6");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 7");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 8");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 9");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 10");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 11");
            sendMessage(true,"Number 12");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception found", "bugger");
        }
    }// End or run
}// End of class

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
    btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    connectWiFi connectwifi = new connectWiFi();
                    connectwifi.start();
                }

            });
}

private void createTableRow(mymessageObject stage) {
    String statusString;
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.statusTable);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tr.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tr.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    TextView tvStatus = new TextView(this);
    tvStatus.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tvStatus.setPadding(2, 1, 1, 2);
    tvStatus.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    if (stage.Status) {statusString = "OK";} else {statusString = "No";};
    tvStatus.setText(statusString); // Status
    TextView tvStage = new TextView(this);
    tvStage.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tvStage.setPadding(2, 1, 1, 2);
    tvStage.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    tvStage.setText(stage.statusMessage); // Stage
    tr.addView(tvStatus);
    tr.addView(tvStage);
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
private class mymessageObject {  // Creates object of status flag and stage message
    boolean Status;
    String statusMessage;
    mymessageObject(boolean newStatus, String newMessage){
        Status = newStatus;
        statusMessage = newMessage;
    }
}
private void sendMessage (boolean status, String stageMessage) { // Handle sending message back to handler

    Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
    message.obj = new mymessageObject(status,stageMessage);
    handler.sendMessage(message);
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
Message m = Message.obtainMessage();
```

not

```
Message m = handler.obtainMessage();
```

Comment: Hi @H-Bahrami - using Message instead of handler means it can not resolve obtainMessage()...

Comment: He meant Message.obtain() but all that does is grab a Message instance without the target set